# How to programmatically pop up "File Sharing" dialog on windows

Tags: windows, file-sharing

As you might know after right click a folder and choose "**Share with**" -> "**Specific people**" windows will pop up a dialog named "**File Sharing**" and let you choose user account/permission.

**My question is:** Is there any way to pop up this dialog by programming?

Comment: I guess you should answer your own question if you found the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a solution, using ShowShareFolderUI on ntshrui.dll can do this job

See this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762235%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on MSDN